# Change angular router URL scheme

Tags: angular, url, angular-router

When I try to pass some parameters to my URL the angular router provides some URL schemes that I don't really like.

The URLS in [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjpqdmqakrm) example look like this:

`https://whatever.io/crisis-center;id=2;foo=foo`

And I would like them to look like some 'conventional' URLs.

Something like: `https://whatever.io/crisis-center?id=2&foo=foo`

Is there a way to change the URL scheme for the Angular2^ router? If so, any advice or example on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `query parameters` when routing in angular

```
this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center'], { queryParams: { id: 2, 'foo': 'foo' } });
```

Your URL will look like this :

```
http://localhost:4200/crisis-center'?id=2&foo=foo
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. Any tip on how to `navigate` relatively? For instance: im at `name.io/somewhere` and I'd like to navigate to `name.io/somewhere/deeper?id=2&foo=foo`. I just can get 'root' redirects of the URL. Thank you very much! (as soon as I can accept the answer I'll do so)

Comment: Import  `ActivatedRouter` and make its instance in constructor, then use it while navigating, `this.router.navigate(['crisis-center'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: { id: 2, 'foo': 'foo' } })`

Comment: How should I get this.activatedRoute? I get an error saying that the property doesn't exist in my component.

Comment: `import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'`

Comment: I forgot to add it into the constructor thank you again